# How to get actual width of a label on a tabitem which is not the displayed tabitem

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working with VS 2015 on a WPF application. On one of my windows I have a `TabControl` with two `TabItems`.

On each of these tabs I have - for example - a `Label` control which has the same name.

In my application I have a `Save` method which saves the positions and sizes of controls on these tabs to a database.

The `Label` is the only control which is making problems. The size of the `Label` on the currently displayed `TabItem` is saved correctly (by `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`).

But the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the label on the not displayed `TabItem` are 0.

Just when I open the other `TabItem` and save the data, the size is correct in the database.

Do I have to refresh the controls somehow before saving their position and sizes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the tabcontrol has only one active content area so tabs that were never displayed will not be initialized as view. How about not saving the viewstate of controls that were never displayed anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem.
Instead of setting the size of the label to autosize i gave it a static size.
Now the label properties ActualWidth and ActualHeight are not 0 anymore and can be saved correctly.
It's a little bit weird, that the label can make such problems when it's set to autosize and not on the currently displayed tabitem.